# Runtime exceptions are caught with ACRA and not displayed on Logcat

Tags: android, logcat, acra

I have successfully implemented [ACRA(Application Crash Report for Android)](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) on my project and error reports are sent to Google docs correctly.
But...
when an exception happens on my app, it doesnt show up on my logcat and this is what i get:

```
ACRA caught a RuntimeException exception for com.my.project. Building report.
```

So ACRA catches errors and doesn't let Logcat display what happened. I'm currently developing my application and i don't have the time to open Google docs for every issue happens. Should i disable ACRA on development and enable it on production?

Comment: So if I understand, the sole purpose of your post is to ask if you should disable ACRA while you're in development, and only enable it on production? My opinions are a) yes, and b) SO is not the right place to post this question.

Comment: The purpose of my qs is to know why ACRA avoids doing the followings at the same time: 1.dumping errors to Logcat and 2.sending them to Google docs

Comment: You might re-read your post then, and edit it to convey this, since the only thing you currently mention about sending reports to Google docs is "error reports are sent to Google docs correctly". One thing to consider though... if reports are not being delivered, does your app have INTERNET permission?

Comment: Reports are delivered to Google and report sending is working fine.but(my problem is:) errors will not show up on my local eclipse's Logcat anymore.When i disable ACRA they will show up and when i reenable ACRA they stop showing up. Please do not close/vote down a qs because you dont understand the point.Be nice:-)

Comment: I didn't downvote though I did vote to close; this is why it takes 5 people to agree (and I have no personal vesting on if others vote to close, I happily accept that I can be wrong in thinking the question is inappropriate for SO). I do understand your point now, but I still hold my initial opinions (both of them, one of which did answer your question). Beyond that... since ACRA is an open source product, I'm sure it would be trivial to modify it to log the exception it catches. It appears that ErrorReporter.java is the place to look; add the log to uncaughtException().

Comment: @drfanai Are you filtering the logcat? In my apps, I can see the errors in the logcat even with ACRA, but their level is reduced to a warning, instead of an error.

Comment: mah you are absolutely right and thanks for caring. @Raghav Sood what you proposed solved my issue.Please consider adding your comment as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you filtering the logcat? In my apps, I can see the errors in the logcat even with ACRA, but their level is reduced to a warning, instead of an error.

Try lowering your filtering of the LogCat.

Answer (score 1):

You have something else going on in your app (or your IDE) that is causing this behaviour.

ACRA does not swallow any Exceptions. They will appear in your log as well as in your error repository (in your case a Google doc).