# No StackTrace of catched exception (by ACRA) in LogCat of IDE (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat, acra

I'm using [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) lib for getting crashes of my app.

It work fine (I receive crash-reports on my server with stackTrace and logCat info). But in my IDE (Eclipse) in logCat I see only this line, when I throw exception:

> E/ACRA(18776): ACRA caught a IndexOutOfBoundsException exception for com.example.myapp. Building report.

So I able to read stackTrace of catched error only on my server... And, of course, if I disable ACRA initialization in my app I can see stackTrace of throwing error.

Also I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920503/runtime-exceptions-are-caught-with-acra-and-not-displayed-on-logcat), but it do not help me, as I already have "verbose" filter in logCat in my IDE (Eclipse).

**UPD_0:**

As I understand, this issue caused by Android version >=5 (Lolipop). I test on Nesus 4 (**ver 5.1**) and on LG g3s, **ver.5.0.2**. On thses devices there are no stackTrace of catched error in IDE's logCat. On devices with Android <5 (Lolipop) everything is all write and I can see error detailes in logCat of Eclipse.

**UPD_1:**

If read logs from cmd (adb logcat) everithing is all write. So there is problem with Eclipse...

Comment: And what happens if you use logcat direclty (outside of Eclipse)? http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: @William, I try using logCat from cmd and everithing is all wright - I can see error's detailed logs with tag "ACRA". So it's a problem with Eclipse?..

Comment: I have the same problem in android studio. have you found a solution yet ?

Comment: @miladzahedi, as I remember, there was a problem with old version of ARCA. So I just use the lastest one and problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

If it's showing in the adb logcat, then it's a problem with either Eclipse or with your Eclipse config.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but how can I fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used Eclipse since 2008. Use IntelliJ/Android Studio. Use adb. Submit a patch for Eclipse?

Comment: `i have this problem with android stuido too.